# unable to view image from database

Tags: php

I can't view my image from mysql database.
I used curl to download the image to mysql database, and im trying to view the image, im getting error from firefox debugger.

i already created my database in blob fromat.

**Here is my code for downloading the image**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "recorduser";
$password = "password123";
$database = "record";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database); //    Check connection if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }


$ch = curl_init ("http://www.albaldnews.com/upimages/news/thumb_albald11-04- 2014-993734.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch,        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1); 
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);

$rawdata = addslashes($rawdata);


$sql = "INSERT INTO picture (image)VALUES ('$rawdata')"; 
$result =   mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

?>
```

**And the code for viewing the image as flow;**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>dispaly image</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />         

</head>

<body>


<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "recorduser";
$password = "password123";
$database = "record";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database); 
//Check connection if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM picture";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$img = $row["image"];

echo '<img src="'.$img.'" />';


?>
```

**Firefox error code:**

```
<img src="http://192.168.206.129/rssfeed/showimage.php" alt="The image   “http://192.168.206.129/rssfeed/showimage.php” cannot be displayed because it   contain errors>
```

Comment: As a suggestion, you shouldn't store images in a database, only their locations on a drive. Forgive me if you did follow this method, as I only skimmed your code.

Comment: @Fred -ii i used curl to download the image from http.

Comment: @William Callahan i want to store the image in database not folder.

Comment: Where are the curly quotes `“ ”` coming from and the `alt`? Surely they're part of something, they just don't appear *out of the blue* like that. Then I see the word "rssfeed".... *hm...*

Comment: Was the image saved in DB as BLOB? I noticed your comment in the answer below, so that kind of made me *raise a brow*. Now, about my comment just above...?

Comment: @ Fred -ii the ` curly quotes “ ” coming from and the alt` coming from firefox debugger. when i lunch firefox debugger this error produce. hope i understand your question, is this what you asking for ?

Comment: @Fred -ii- yes the image stored in blob as i mention in my question.

Comment: I don't know enough about curl to comment about that, but if you're wanting to insert raw data, `addslashes()` may be affecting it. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Now, MySQL may be trying to grab every row, can you try using a `where` clause to see if that makes a difference? Or do a `LIMIT 1`

Comment: @ Fred -ii- i removed `addslashes()` and replace it with `mysqli_real_escape_string` but same error im getting.i add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` but not getting anything.

Answer (score 1):

finally it work.

I replaced  `echo $img;` with `echo $img = $row["image"];`